# Socket.io with express.session

Tags: node.js, sockets

What I'm doing is registering a user and creating session using the new userId in expressjs. Till this point I'm doing it right and it works. But I need the same session variable for my io.
Client Side:

```
var userRegisterData={
                    url:baseURL+'userRegisterData',
                    dataServer:{
                            username: user.username,
                            useremail: user.useremail,
                            userpassword: user.userpassword
                    }
                }
               runAjax.runajax_function(userRegisterData,function(userData){
                    console.log(userData.process);
                });

socket.on('getMyData', function(data){
    $scope.userData = data;
    console.log($scope.userData);
});
```

Server Side:
ExpressJs

```
app.post('/userRegisterData', function(req, res) {
    //db activities
    session.userId = result.userId;
    //so here i set the session variable from db
});
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  //db activities using session.userId (I need the session.userId for db purpose)
  socket.emit('getMyData', result);
});
```

Now when I start the server for the first time, I get the error that `userId is undefined` in `io.on`

Well I can understand that `io.on` is getting executed before my `app.post`. I'm very much new to expressJs and socket.io and I tried using if, that solves the problem of not getting any error when I start the server for the first time but also it never works again as the `io.on` scope already got executed.

What I need to achieve is that, if the session variable is not present in express-session, let the io.on doesn't do anything, when the session variable is available only the it triggers.

Comment: Should it be "req.session.userId" not "session.userId"?

Comment: No that is not the problem, because the `session.userId` is generated from db. I skipped the db part here to make it clean.

Comment: When I start the server for the first time, I get the error that `userId is undefined`

Comment: If session is stored in DB, I think you should wait until DB is connected before using it.

Comment: Exactly, but how do I do that, I'm unable to do so.

Comment: Which DB you are using? I need more details. Could you add more details like which DB you are using, what modules you are using something like that?

Comment: Ok all I need to know is how do I pass a parameter in `socket.on` from client side and read it on server side, because I almost found a way to deal with this. Need Help.

Comment: Use socket.emit from client side to tell the server that session needed to create(POST /userRegisterData) with some parameters.  Then response to the client that telling "Session is created. Now I'm ready to communicate via socket". After than establish socket related events to client/server side both, not in io.on('connection').